# How to add VBA to Excel using addins in C++?

Tags: c++, excel, vba, excel-addins

I am building an addin in C++ to add functionality to Excel.

There is one problem. I cannot undo all the actions called by this addin.

I did some research, and it seems Excel clears the undo stack before VBA operations.

I found that there is a method called onundo, which allows me to call a VBA.

However, I need to define a VBA in current workbook.

Is there a way to add the VBA function automatically in my C++ program? Otherwise, the user needs to add the function, which is not convenient.